# Filtering the user data with the age max and age min while date of birth is present in schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I want to filter user data according to the age max and age min but I don't have age field in user schema.I have Date of birth field. What mongoose query should I write to get the desired result.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: { type: String, required: false },
bnr: {type: String, required: false},
firstname : {type: String, required: false},
lastname : {type: String, required: false},
profilepic: String,
dob: {type: Date, required:true}
},{timestamps: true}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom function to findout Age using DOB. In your filter function in which you are filtering the Age on MAX or MIN, call this function from your controller:

```
function getAge(DOB) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(DOB);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age = age - 1;
    }

    return age;
}
```

This will return Age. For example, I am creating a dummy functions:

```
function filter(res, req, next){
   var age = getAge(res.DOB);
   //and the your max or min calculations...
}
```